# Flexbox, how can I have a one of the flex items contain two rows

Tags: html, css, angularjs, layout, flexbox

I would like to have a flex item contain stacked elements.  I know that I can use a wrapper div inside of the first flex item and add the content inside with a property of `display: block`.

I am however using Angular's `ng-repeat` and I need all of the items inside of the flex container to be siblings.

Here is a simple demo of what I have so far http://jsbin.com/puhoma/edit?html,css,output . I would like the orange box and aqua box to get closer together.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex > div {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 30%;
}
.flex > div:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
.flex > div:last-child {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
  top: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>orange box and aqua box need to take up one row together</div>
    <div>Hellothis is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test</div>
    <div>Hello 2this is a long test sentence this is a</div>
    <div class="hi">Get me closer to Mr. Orange</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: remove the `height: 10%` for the orange box?

Comment: `flexbox` is not something you'd use for creating a grid if you are looking for that...

Comment: @kukkuz I think that's not what he means. I think the last block needs to fill up the whitespace and be even with the other red blocks.

Comment: yes :) that's why I said flexbox can't used for something like a grid... you have use css columns, masonary or something like that

Comment: maybe you can use Isotope - masonry layout like this one  [https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/89ufopaL/1/]

Comment: @kukkus I am trying to create a grid with flex box, I am now noticing the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your original post, `flexbox`  is not the ideal way to go in this case, but if you really wanted to do it using flexboxes for whatever reason, you could set the `margin-top` to a negative value to get the aqua box closer to the orange one.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex > div {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 30%;
}
.flex > div:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
.flex > div:last-child {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
  top: 1;
  margin-top: -55px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>orange box and aqua box need to take up one row together</div>
    <div>Hellothis is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test</div>
    <div>Hello 2this is a long test sentence this is a</div>
    <div class="hi">Get me closer to Mr. Orange</div>
  </div>
</body>
```